# 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'uuid' - Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-mptt

I'm using `django-mptt` to create a tree-like structure for my `Section` model. Unfortunately, when I go to serialize it with `drf-writable-nested`, I get an error. This error only occurs when the `url` field is added to the serializer.

Also, when I remove `uuid` from the custom lookup field, the error is just replaced with `pk`.

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55173445/9137820, but I'm not accessing any of the data directly, so I'm not sure how that could be the issue.

Code:

```
# models.py

class Section(MPTTModel, TimeStampedModel):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid_lib.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    objects = TreeManager()
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', related_name='section_children', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

```
# serializers.py

class SectionSerializer(UniqueFieldsMixin, WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    children = serializers.ListField(source='get_children', child=RecursiveField())

    class Meta:
        model = Section
        fields = ['url', 'uuid', 'name', 'children']

        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'uuid'},
        }
```

```
# views.py

class SectionDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Section.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SectionSerializer
    lookup_field = 'uuid'
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 75, in update
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 548, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 515, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1661, in to_representation
    return [self.child.to_representation(item) if item is not None else None for item in data]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1661, in <listcomp>
    return [self.child.to_representation(item) if item is not None else None for item in data]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 515, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 399, in to_representation
    url = self.get_url(value, self.view_name, request, format)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 335, in get_url
    lookup_value = getattr(obj, self.lookup_field)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/v1/sections/3b15cbda-f61e-4a00-89fb-817beed10b14/
Exception Value: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'uuid'
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging and this is what I can find. Dictionaries and OrderedDicts don't save keys and values as class attributes. So you cant retrieve them using `getattr()`. You need to request a method or attribute like `dict.keys()` or `dict.values()` from the `OrderedDict`. You can't use a key name.

See this example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

g = OrderedDict()

g['test'] = 1

g = getattr(g, 'values')

print(list(g())[0])
```

That works fine but if you changed

```
g = getattr(g, 'values')
```

to

```
g = getattr(g, 'test')
```

It produces the same error you're experiencing

Comment: Same error, unfortunately. One odd thing that I noticed: The OrderedDict has the `uuid` attribute. `OrderedDict([('uuid', 'e8d3d17b-55f0-415c-b279-9e32e869e0fb'), ('name', 'Testing'), ('get_children', [])])`

Comment: Does using a different field produce the same error? For example using `name` instead of `uuid`?

Comment: Yep, and if I remove the custom lookup field altogether, `uuid` is replaced with `pk`.

Comment: I found that you can't use a key name like `uuid` for this. See my updated answer for an explanation.

Comment: I'm not using `getattr` myself, it's being called by a library that I'm using somewhere.

Comment: I know, but you still have to work around the fact that `getattr` is being used